# Xcode : Need understanding

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, user-interface

I know the breakpoints. But not known about the thing that look like the diamond. Take a look at the image shown, it is present at lines no. 16, 28 and 33. When I click on that, Xcode compiles the project. It is hard to get some details about that.

[image]

Comment: Looking at your tools, not understanding something, and then asking about it, puts you leagues ahead of many "developers". Congratulations.

Answer (score 1):

The diamonds are symbols to indicate test results.

To use them run the tests by selecting menu item `Test` from menu `Product` or pressing <kbd>⌘U</kbd>

Comment: Also, clicking on one of them will run the test case or test class to which they correspond.

Answer (score 1):

Test cases are starts with the method name -(void)testLogin, those methods are mentioned in diamond , we can run that test individully or overall test cases can be run by choosing the target as test. 
This can be achieved by long press on the play button, which will provide you with 3 option, in that choose test. This will perform all the test cases and provide you the success or failure test cases

Comment: whatever answer which helps you most, Approve that answer by tick mark